# Stripes for Rebellious Conduct

Tags: rambam, reward-punishment

This phrase is used by Rambam in Mishneh Torah but I can't find any elucidation of what it means. I understand it to mean a punishment of a a lesser degree than lashes, something like "a mark on your character / name(?)" Any one know of a source defining it.

Edit: examples "[Even one who partakes of sacrificial food that contracts impurity of Scriptural origin] is liable for lashes only when he partakes of it after its blood is cast [on the altar]. If, by contrast, he partakes of it before the casting of its blood, he is not liable for lashes because he partook of impure sacrificial food. He does, however, receive stripes for rebellious conduct." (Pesulei Hamukdashim - Chapter 18, ¶12 as translated by Eliyahu Touger available at http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/682956/jewish/Mishneh-Torah.htm)

"It is forbidden for a person to make motions with his hands or feet or wink with his eyes to one of the ariyot, to share mirth with her or to act frivolously with her. It is even forbidden to smell her perfume or gaze at her beauty. A person who performs any of these actions intentionally should be given stripes for rebellious conduct." (Issurei Biah - Chapter Twenty One, ¶2 as translated by Eliyahu Touger available at http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/682956/jewish/Mishneh-Torah.htm)

Comment: Here's an article I found on the subject thanks to the answer below: http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/14083-stripes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Makkat mardut* in Hebrew. The standard punishment for violating a *rabbinic* prohibition, vs. the more serious biblical ones. Thus: knowingly, purposely, ate beef boiled in milk despite witnesses' warnings? 39 biblically-mandated lashes (assuming he can take 39 of them). Knowingly, purposely ate chicken boiled in milk? *Makkat mardut.* Enough lashes that the rabbis feel make a point. (According to some, enough to make the transgressor apologize; there are several different interpretations on the detail.) But the point is -- it's a rabbinic prohibition.

Comment: More accurately it's a rabbinic punishment. It's theoretically possible that a biblical prohibition could have no biblical punishment but have a rabbinic punishment

Comment: @DoubleAA for Isur Asse?!